# Change colour of cursor indicator in ruler-mode

Tags: colors

I am using ruler-mode and would like to change the background and foreground colour of the cursor indicator.

Had a go with `ruler-mode-current-column` but emacs is complaining that ruler-mode-current-column is not a face.

```
(defun lex-ruler ()

  (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
            (lambda ()
          (ruler-mode 1)))

  (set-face-attribute 'ruler-mode-current-column nil
              :background "#ff4500" :foreground "#ffffff"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `customize` system is the best way to go here. It groups all of the settings for the mode together, and that includes the various faces the mode defines. Use `M-x customize-group ruler-mode` to go directly to the mode’s settings. Each face is concisely described, and includes a sample, so you should have no trouble finding the one(s) you wish to modify.

Edit:

It’s certainly a face here:

```lisp
(face-attribute 'ruler-mode-current-column :foreground)
"yellow"

(set-face-attribute 'ruler-mode-current-column nil :foreground "blue")
nil

(face-attribute 'ruler-mode-current-column :foreground)
"blue"
```

What does it do when you try it?

Comment: Have encountered `ruler-mode-current-column`, but still need to do this in elisp.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in elisp?

Comment: Because I take care of various versions of emacs and want to just send the `.el` file.

Comment: The customize interface saves your settings as elisp in your init file; is that not good enough?

Comment: Could I pick up the code from there?

Comment: I do not like it.  It just utilises `custom-set-faces` with `(custom-set-faces'(ruler-mode-current-column ((t (:inherit ruler-mode-default :background "orange red" :foreground "#ffffff")))))`.  I want a proper command that does not interfere with what other users might do with their customisations in `custom-set-faces`.

Comment: Why do you say that `custom-set-faces` is not a proper command? If the user’s own customizations come after your own, yours will be overridden. You already know about `set-face-attribute`, of course, so that is an option as well.

Comment: I did, but it seems that `ruler-mode-current-column` is not a face.

Comment: I got `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid face" ruler-mode-current-column)`.

Comment: Ok it works if I execute the command in the buffer

Comment: I guess the face isn’t autoloaded like the function `ruler-mode` is, so I suppose you need to `(require 'ruler-mode)` before you can modify it.

Comment: Yes, that did it.